# Generate touch screen events on android through usb

Tags: android, usb

I want to control Android using the open accessory mode (usb) from another device 
Is it possible to generate touch screen events : act as a click or multi touch event  or write on the keyboard ?
If so , is it possible to keep the app which does that running in background and fully control the smart phone from outside ?